# Cython precision and data types

Tags: python, types, cython

I understand in cython some precision is lost, because a cython float is not the same as a python float. Consequently I redifined a variable as follows:

```
cdef long double variable=1*10**-10
print variable
0.0
```

This failed however:

```
cdef long double variable=0.0000000001
print variable
1e-10
```

was successful. I need to perform relatively precise calculations so I am keen to understand this behavior.

Comment: You may want to examine the cross-compiled output.

Comment: What happens if you add decimal points (e.g. 1.*10.**-10. )?

Answer (score 2):

See here, it seems this bug is fixed in Cython 3.0

https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/2133